# WebLogic Diagnostic Framework (WLDF): Alternatives?

Tags: performance, monitoring, weblogic, trace, visualvm

WLDF (WebLogic Diagnostic Framework) allows many performance-related analyses - in particular resource demands tracking and tracing across classes and methods. In that sense, it is similar to a profiler - however, it works on the server side, and is bound to the particular product/vendor.

Are there any other products (maybe even open/free) which offer similar level of detail? I'm not interested in "conventional" monitoring products such as JMX, VisualVM, Hyperic etc. but in low-level, detailed tracing and request tracking.

Many thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

The free version of http://appdynamics.com/ is probably your best bet. It does the low level detailed tracing without the traditional overhead of a profiler (so yes, you can run it in prod).